# Reward for Cart Pole Problem Reinforcement Learning

Tags: reinforcement-learning

For the cart pole balancing problem, I am wondering why so many implementations of reinforcement learning to solve for a controller have a reward function that awards -1 every time the pole falls over, and 0 for every time step in which the pole remains upright.

How would this train the system, if falling over immediately yields the same reward as falling over after a minute of balancing?

Comment: 99.9% of readers won't know what the *"Cart Pole balancing problem"* is, so please edit in a citation.

Answer (score 0):

The information you're missing at the minute is the [time taken to reach that reward](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/221402/understanding-the-role-of-the-discount-factor-in-reinforcement-learning).

The RL algorithms when performing updates to the controller will typically use a discounted reward, in which a `-1` reward that happens sooner is less preferable than a `-1` reward that happens later.

For example, if the pole is slightly to the left of centre; we will receive a `-1` sooner by moving the pole all the way to the left, than if we move the pole all the way to the right. Therefore, when the pole is to the left, moving it to the right is better. And when the pole is to the right, moving it to the left is better. Thus balancing the pole around the centre.

In terms of how the reward is discounted, we typically use a discount factor parameter between 0 and 1 to multiply the reward per time-step. For example, if by selecting the left action we get a `-1` reward in 1 time-step, and the right action will give us a `-1` reward in 2 time-steps, then the *expected discounted rewards* (with a discount factor of 0.99) would be `0.99*-1` for left (`-0.99`) and `0.99*0.99*-1` for right (`-0.9801`), so choosing right would be better.

Also, FYI - https://stats.stackexchange.com is a better place for asking RL questions, as the question wasn't really about coding.

Comment: Ah I understand. Thank you very much. I will use the correct exchange in the future.